# How do I determining the exact percentile among a sample given the 10, 25, 50, and 90 percentiles

Tags: mathematical-statistics, estimation, quantiles

**Background**: I'm trying to provided employees or decision makers with comparative wages analysis based on national or regional wage estimates.  I'm developing a tool to provide employees and clients an understanding of what their wages are comparative to others.

**Question**:  Using a standard distribution and given values for the 10, 25, 50, 75, and 90 percentiles could I determine the exact percentile of any given value?

For example, lets say i'm a police officer and I make an annual wage of 65,000 or 31.25 hourly.  Looking at the national wage estimates provided by the Bureau of Labor Statistics (http://www.bls.gov/oes/current/oes333051.htm), can I calculate the exact percent or percentile the employee would be in?  How would I calculate this information?

I would think the person making $65K would be near 75 percentile, maybe something like 71.5%.

Thanks in advance for your help.

[image: image 1]

Comment: The graphic is exceptionally misleading.  *The horizontal axis is not linear.*  It is visually symmetric, implying that the distance between the "10%" and "25%" marks should equal the distance between the "90%" and "75%" marks.  But those two distances are 42,910-33,430=9480 and 96,110-76,160=19950. Its Lie Factor of 19950/9480=2.1 is high.  Thus, the interpolation methods suggested by the graphic are unlikely to be accurate.  Could you tell us anything more about this "standard distribution"?

Comment: whuber, thanks for the feedback.  After reviewing your comment,  I can't see anything on the BLS website, which gives the standard distribution.  I see the population, RMS, and mean.  Also this page (http://www.bls.gov/oes/oes_perc.htm) doesn't mention anything helpful either.